# Flask app not displaying css elements for mobile (works fine on desktop)

Tags: html, css, iphone, flask, emulation

I have a flask web app that's working just fine on desktop but the CSS is not being applied to some of my pages and I'm not sure why. Some fonts are different for some reason on mobile but most notably, any CSS adjustments I make for the select tag below do not seem to take.

[Works great when I emulate a mobile device on desktop browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf0KB.png)

[but the fonts are different on mobile and the select tag CSS doesn't seem to work at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Msdt.png)

I even tried adding in-line CSS for the select tag, but it didn't have any effect.

In my header:
`<link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />`

In my HTML file:

```
<div class="size-selection">
    <select class="option-selector" id="size">
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="L">L</option>
        <option value="XL">XL</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.option-selector {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #979797;
  padding: 7.5px 10px 8.5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.42;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.85714em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 10px center;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.size-selection {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  max-width: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I'm pretty lost and any insight would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for days. Not even sure how to troubleshoot because the browser device emulators don't even show the issue on mobile devices.